# Linking to CRT (unresolved external symbol WinMainCRTStartup)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm trying to create a windows application and statically link to the CRT. I'm getting this error,

> LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol WinMainCRTStartup

I'm compiling with this command line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe" /c main.cpp /O2 /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Include" /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /Zi /MT /nologo
```

and linking with this command line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe" user32.lib libcmt.lib kernel32.lib main.obj crt_win64.obj /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DEBUG /nologo /MACHINE:x64 /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Lib"
```

As you can see I'm using the /MT switch on the compiler and using the /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS switch on the linker.

I'm also linking to libcmt.lib.

The signature of my main function is

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What the signature of you main function?

Comment: Try to use `VC\Lib\amd64` in library path for x64 build

Comment: frymode: That was it! Thank you so much. If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Necroposting*.

Here's a bunch of useful stuff (that I encountered in the past when dealing with various challenges) about *VStudio* (*C* / *C++*) builds:

- [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546)
- [[SO]: Simstring (python) installation in windows (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794384/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546)
- [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)
- [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583411/4788546)

Of course, one way is to manually specify every path, but that can be very painful (especially when cross-building). 
That's where *VCVarsAll* (also *VSDevCmd*, but I prefer the former) comes into play. It sets all the *VC* related paths (*.lib* files path and even build tools') for the current build configuration, so you don't have to worry about them. Check [[MS.Docs]: Use the Microsoft C++ toolset from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line) for more details.

Generally, ***vcvarsall.bat*** (might want to also check [[MS.MSDN.Social]: Where is vcvarsall.bat file?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1071be0e-2a46-4c30-9546-ea9d7c4755fa/where-is-vcvarsallbat-file?forum=visualstudiogeneral)) is located in:

- *VStudio 2005* (*8*) and above:

  - ***${VSTUDIO_INSTALL_DIR}\VC***
- *VStudio 2017* (*15*) and above:

  - ***${VSTUDIO_INSTALL_DIR}\VC\Auxiliary\Build***

What your build commands could look like:

```bat
:: Setup build for pc064
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

:: Compile
cl /nologo /O2 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /Zi /MD /Fomain.obj /c main.cpp

:: Link
link /NOLOGO /DEBUG /MACHINE:x64 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OUT:main.exe main.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib
```

Of course, you could create a *Makefile.mak* for the build: [[MS.Docs]: Running NMAKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/running-nmake).

**Note**: Since *vcvarsall.bat* adds (lots of) directories to the existing environment variables (*PATH*, *INCLUDE*, *LIBPATH*, ...), launching it multiple times (switching between *pc032* and *pc064* builds) might result in the variable *char* limit (32760) to be reached (which will trigger problems). Therefore, it's best to keep one *Cmd* window open for each target *CPU* architecture (and don't launch *VCVarsAll* multiple times).