# Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, extern, lnk2001

I'm trying to include some C code I found in our C++ project. The function is defined like this in the  C file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 extern char *dtoa(double, int, int, int *, int *, char **);
 extern char *g_fmt(char *, double);
 extern void freedtoa(char*);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

 char *
g_fmt(register char *b, double x)
{
```

The VS project I'm including this in is creating a dll. The file is being compiled as C, other files in the project are being compiled as C++.

I added a header to include in my C++ files

```
#ifndef G_FMT_H
#define G_FMT_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 extern char *dtoa(double, int, int, int *, int *, char **);
 extern char *g_fmt(char *, double);
 extern void freedtoa(char*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif //G_FMT_H
```

In another project in the solution I include my header and try calling the g_fmt function.

```
#include "header.h"
...
g_fmt(my_array, 2.0);
```

This project is linking to the other one, I'm able to call C++ functions in the first library without any issues. However, adding the above line gives me a lnk2001 error .

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol g_fmt
```

I've found a number of other questions about mixing C and C++ and I seem to have done everything necessary with the extern keywords in the right places, however I'm still not able to link. Is there anything specific I need to do in VS2010?

Comment: so you can use dtoa but not g_fmt?

Comment: no, I mean I can use C++ functions declared elsewhere in the same library. I've read in other posts you can mix C and C++ in the same project, maybe that isn't quite true?

Comment: It's true, the point is how do you export functions? Usually you need a __declspec(dllexport) or a def file. What method do you use here?

Comment: The linker is looking for the actual function's object code (or import library stub).  It isn't looking at header files or C++ source code -- the compilation stage has passed.  So where is the `g_fmt` function actually implemented?  Is it in a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question is for *VStudio 2010*, but applies to any version**.

In *C* or *C++*, considering that a module may consist of multiple objects, every object should be clearly delimited. Also, every object (*.c* or *.cpp* file) should have its own header file. So, you should have one header file and one *.c(xx)* file for the *C* functions (*3* in your example). 
Also, as a general guideline, try to be consistent when naming files and macros: your *header.h* file uses *G_FMT_H* macro as include guard.
Try reorganizing your *.h* and *.c* files to something like:

- *functions.h*:

  ```c
  #pragma once

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  if defined(FUNCTIONS_STATIC)
  #    define FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API
  #  else
  #    if defined(FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS)
  #      define FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #    else
  #      define FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #    endif
  #  endif
  #else
  #  define FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API
  #endif

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API char *dtoa(double, int, int, int*, int*, char**);
  FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API char *g_fmt(char*, double);
  FUNCTIONS_EXPORT_API void freedtoa(char*);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif
  ```
- The corresponding implementation (*functions.c*):

  ```c
  #define FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS
  #include "functions.h"


  char *dtoa(double, int, int, int*, int*, char**)
  {
      //function statements
  }


  char *g_fmt(char*, double)
  {
      //function statements
  }


  void freedtoa(char*)
  {
      //function statements
  }
  ```

2 things to notice here (besides reorganizing and renaming) in the header file:

- The ***extern*** storage specifier for each function is gone
- Exporting logic: your project will define now *FUNCTIONS_EXPORT* (from *functions.c*, or **desirable** to be a *VStudio* project setting - anyway, somewhere **before** `#include "functions.h"`)

  - When this project (*functions.c*) will be compiled, the functions will be exported (due to the macro definition)
  - When the header file will be included in another project (that doesn't define *FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS*), the functions will be marked as imported, and the linker will search for them in the imported *.lib*(s) - one of them should be the one generated by this project
  - To be more rigorous, you could replace the *FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS* (and remove its definition from *functions.c*) by a macro that's **automatically** defined by *VStudio IDE*: *${YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTS* (e.g. if your *Dll* project is called *ExportFunctionsProject.vc(x)proj*, then the macro name will be ***EXPORTFUNCTIONSPROJECT_EXPORTS***)
  - You can check the macro name in *VStudio (2010) IDE*: ***Project Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Preprocessor** -> **Preprocessor definitions***. For more details, check [[MS.Docs]: /D (Preprocessor Definitions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/hhzbb5c8(v=vs.100))

Similar (or related) issues:

- [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)
- [[SO]: Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177222/4788546)
- [[SO]: When using fstream in a library I get linker errors in the executable (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558269/4788546)
- [[SO]: C++ dll export undefined (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551640/4788546)