# Including header files from libraries when building a new library

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, declspec

To be clear:
I'm aware that the below example demonstrates a dll-dependancy, i.e. one library is not self-containe, but depends on another library to function.

Let's say I'm creating a runtime library, Utility.dll, which contains various useful functions of general nature.
I create a header file Utility.h to be included in other files which need to use Utility.dll.
The header file looks like

```
#ifndef _UTILITY_H
#define _UTILITY_H

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_EXPORT void foo();
DLL_EXPORT void foo2();
....

#endif
```

When I compile the source code file Utility.cpp into machine code (into Utility.dll) I make sure BUILD_DLL is defined so DLL_EXPORT gets replaced with __declspec(dllexport). This makes the functions be exported to the .dll file.
Whenever I include the header Utility.h and link with the import library (Utility.lib for MS VS, libUtility.a for g++) and do **not** define BUILD_DLL, the function declarations in Utility.h begin with __declspec(dllimport) instead, telling the compiler that the functions are imported from a .dll (so to speak).

Now, let's say I'm also building **another** library, MyLibrary.dll, which wants to use some of the useful functions in Utility.dll. Similarily, I would create MyLibrary.h as

```
#ifndef _MYLIBRARY_H
#define _MYLIBRARY_H

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_EXPORT void myLibraryFunc1();
....

#endif
```

When I compile MyLibrary.cpp into MyLibrary.dll I'm including Utility.h and also linking against the Utility import library.

This leads us to my **question**:
Since I define BUILD_DLL also when I compile MyLibrary.dll, this means that the function declarations in Utility.h also will read

```
__declspec(dllexport) void foo();
__declspec(dllexport) void foo2();
....
```

Not

```
__declspec(dllimport) void foo();
__declspec(dllimport) void foo2();
```

Don't we want it to be __declspec(dllimport) for the function declarations in Utility.h when we compile MyLibrary.dll, and __declspec(dllexport) for the function declarations in MyLibrary.h?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the inclusion of utility.h with a `#undef BUILD_DLL #include "utility.h" #define BUILD_DLL`?

Comment: That's a good point. However, if I include both MyLibrary.h and Utility.h in a program, wouldn't that line cause BUILD_DLL to always be defined when the compiler processes MyLibrary.h, because you say #define BUILD_DLL ?

Comment: You don't have to do the `#define BUILD_DLL` after `#include "utility.h" `.  I was just showing how you can get rid of a symbol, include a file and then re define the symbol.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip, I did not know about #undef before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely the reason why you normally don't name such macros `BUILD_DLL`, but `BUILD_UTILITY` and `BUILD_MYLIBRARY` or similar. Likewise, the declspec macro should not be `DLL_EXPORT`, but `UTILITY_EXPORT` and `MYLIBRARY_EXPORT` (or perhaps `UTILITY_API` and `MYLIBRARY_API`).

Comment: [Here's a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581837/linker-error-when-calling-a-c-function-from-c-code-in-different-vs2010-project/30583411#30583411).