# Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I am attempting to use Excel VBA's ability to access and use functions from DLL files.

example:

```
Private Declare Function funcName Lib _
"<filePath\File.dll>" _
(ByRef a As Double, ByRef b As Double) As Double
```

---

Following the instructions from [Mircosoft's tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms235636.aspx) on how to create a DLL file, leads to 3 warnings ([C4273](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273)) when I try to build the project, for the 3 functions declared:

```
'MathLibrary::Functions::Add': inconsistent dll linkage,
'MathLibrary::Functions::Multiply': inconsistent dll linkage,
'MathLibrary::Functions::AddMultiply': inconsistent dll linkage
```

When the VBA in Excel tries to access the created .dll file from this tutorial, it produces a runtime error ([453](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251579.aspx)): 'Can't find DLL entry point Add in "path\file.dll".

---

I am a novice when it comes to the C\C++ language.
I have spent over 6 hours of:

- trying to make tweaks to the vanilla tutorial
- starting over
- googling for help, and similar issues
- making tweaks to the statements within VBA

And yet I feel further from a solution.

I am running 32-bit Excel on 64-bit Windows.

---

Any help would be much appreciated :)

---

**Edit**

Code Files (as requested):

MathLibrary.cpp

```
// MathLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
// Compile by using: cl /EHsc /DMATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS /LD MathLibrary.cpp  

#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "MathLibrary.h"  

namespace MathLibrary
{
    double Functions::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double Functions::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double Functions::AddMultiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + (a * b);
    }
}
```

MathLibrary.h

```
// MathLibrary.h - Contains declaration of Function class  
#pragma once  

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

namespace MathLibrary
{
    // This class is exported from the MathLibrary.dll  
    class Functions
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a + (a * b)  
        static MATHLIBRARY_API double AddMultiply(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

stdafx.h

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

targetver.h

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform,
//     include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support 
//     before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

VBA Module

```
Private Declare Function Add Lib _
"c:\<Path>\MathLibrary.dll" _
(ByRef a As Double, ByRef b As Double) As Double

Sub useAddXL()
    MsgBox Add(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you defined the `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` symbol in your **MathLibrary** project?

Comment: When are you getting the warnings? when building the dll? Could you post the whole code (including _VBA_ or if possible a simple _VB_ script to strip out _Excel_ in order to reduce complexity)? As a remark "access and use functions": a method cannot be simply called as a function (via `GetProcAddress`) because it needs its context (the class). Also, I don't think that _VBA_ supports C++ compiler name mangling.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker, No, I have not defined the `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` symbol; but, according to the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp): 
"By default, the New Project template for a DLL adds PROJECTNAME_EXPORTS to the defined preprocessor symbols for the DLL project"

Comment: @CristiFati, Following the [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp): after "building the solution" in step 5, when I go to the **Error List** window, it displays the `inconsistent dll linkage` [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273) for the 3 functions.

Comment: @carl13 I was able to reproduce the same [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4273](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273) error by following the same [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms235636.aspx) tutorial and botching the `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` with a simple misspelling.  So for example, if you created a project named "MyMathLibrary", even with properly-named source files, you could experience this problem.  I'd recommend walking through again, no problems on VS2015.

Comment: The _inconsistent dll linkage_ message is clearly because of the right macro name not being defined. [\[SO\]: This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581837/linker-error-when-calling-a-c-function-from-c-code-in-different-vs2010-project/30583411#30583411) contains some details  about exporting (_C_) symbols. However, after you'll get past this error, I'm curious if it'll work. As a note, in order to see a *.dll*s exported symbols, use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: @PhilBrubaker, what do you mean you were able to recreate the error 
 by "_... botching the `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` with a simple misspelling_"?

The last time I followed this tutorial, I literally copied & pasted the code from the tutorial; I couldn't have _botched_ the spelling of `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS`

I'm not sure what you mean in your 2nd sentence.  The macro name "**str_EXPORTS**", what is '**str**' suppose to be?

I may download VS2015, but I don't see that helping my understanding of this problem.

**Thank you for your reply.**

Comment: @CristiFati, thank you for the [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) suggestion. 

Using your suggestion on the created DLL from the tutorial, I get this warning `Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.`
`Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.`

So, if I add `#define MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` to the top of `MathLibrary.cpp` (so that the ~symbol is defined), I get this error after I rebuild: 
`'MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS': macro redefinition`

Comment: @CristiFati, 

**EDIT**

thank you for the [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) suggestion. 

Using your suggested program on the created DLL from the tutorial, I get this warning `Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.`
`Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.`

Comment: @CristiFati, 

**EDIT:**

I looked at you SO link.  What I got from it was to add `#define MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` to the top of `MathLibrary.cpp` (so that the ~symbol is defined), but now I get these errors ([C4003](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf9t054c.aspx), [C4603](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514078.aspx)) after I rebuild: 
`'MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS': macro redefinition` , and    
`'MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS': macro is not defined or definition is different after precomplied header use`

Comment: Sorry I knew after that wasn't entirely clear. In a nutshell, I followed the steps in the tutorial using VS 2015 (though the VS version shouldn't matter) and it built fine

Comment: Then I went to the header file and misspelled MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS so that the second #define of MATHLIBRARY_API was effective instead of the first (dllimport instead of dllexport). This recreated the warning you mentioned.

Comment: 'str' as you mention should be 'MATHLIBRARY'.

Comment: Don't worry about the _DependencyWalker_ error. It usually happens when there's a mismatch between its architecture and the target module's (32/64 or viceversa). Anyway in spite of that error it still shows the exported symbols (if any) in the right mid section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this in a solution, as it doesn't fit in an comment.

The ***inconsistent dll linkage*** warning: I copied **your exact code** from the question as it is **at this point** (it might change in the future), and placed it in a newly created *VStudio 2015* project:

- Configuration type: Dynamic Library (*.dll*)
- Using precompiled headers (although, I usually don't do it)

The project compiled **with no warnings**, if I define *MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS* either:

- In the *MathLibrary.cpp* file `#define MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` (**before** `#include "MathLibrary.h"`)
- As a project setting: adding it under *Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions* (next to other macros, separated by semicolons (***;***))

The only thing that I can imagine for you to still get the warning when building yours, is because you are **defining the macro for the wrong configuration**.
Example: you are building your project for *Debug - x86*, but you define the macro for *Release - x86* (or *Debug - x64*).
You must check (it would be better select *All Platfroms* and *All Configurations*, and only define the macro once) that build configurations and settings configurations **match**, like in the image below:

[image: Img0]

But anyway, this warning is benign, the *.dll* is still built, and the symbols exported.

Going further, in your *VBA* module you declare the function name *Add* (plain).
Based on the error message:

> Can't find DLL entry point **Add** in "path\file.dll"

as I specified on one of my comments, I don't think that *Excel* is able to import *C++* style exports because of [[MS.Docs]: Decorated Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names) (*C++* name mangling). While it searches for *Add*, your *.dll* exports the following symbols as shown in the (*Dependency Walker*) image below (you can play with the highlighted button and see how *Dependency Walker* is able to *demangle* those names):

[image: Img1]

Those (gibberish) names you should import from *Excel*, but I doubt that's possible. As a workaround you could either:

- Drop the *C++* features (the class and the namespace) and define and export 3 simple functions
- Write 3 *C* functions (wrappers over the 3 methods), and export the functions not the methods

[[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30583411/4788546) contains all the details (**pay attention** at `extern "C"`: [[MS.Docs]: extern (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp)).

Comment: Welp, following your steps, I tried different combinations of having the definition in the file (before the `#include`) and adding it to the _Project Properties_.  In the end, I have no definition within the file, AND the definition in the _Project Properties_.  **Now there are no errors** after the project is rebuilt.  Perhaps the definition was not in the _Project Properties_ before.

Either way, **You are correct** that VBA does not recognize the mangled names.  And it seems I can not specify the mangled names (syntax error).

**Thank you for your help :D**

Comment: So, were you able to export 3 _C_ style functions from the _.dll_ and import them in _VBA_?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the functions _exported_; using Dependency Walker, it seems the function names are quite mangled (eg. "?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z").

Comment: **EDIT**

I'm fairly certain that the functions _exported_; using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), it seems the function names are _quite mangled_ (eg. `?Add@Functions@MathLibrary@@SANNN@Z`).

VBA doesn't accept this name, with or without quotes (Compiler error: Expected identifier).  If I remove the `?` the ~compiler seems to stop reading the name at the `@` and starts checking for the key work `Lib`, but finds `Functions`.

Comment: It works "manually" importing it from _C_. Although the symbols that you are trying to export, are methods in a class, there's no _OOP_ (_C++_) involved, they are basically 3 functions wrapped in a class. Declare and export them as simple functions: `Add`, `Multiply` and `AddMultiply` (lose the class and namespace).