# How to Grab dll message-dispatching procedure and redirect to python stdout?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to proceed and if it is feasible or not in general.

I working with external DLL to control my mechanical delay line.

This API has it internal procedure for message output in separate window. I have a strong desire to catch this message flow and present in my python (PyQT5) written application.

In API description there is a function:

```
int LS_SetProcessMessagesProc(void *pProc);
```

Function returns either 0 or 1, if there is no error or it is present, respectively.

According to dll description 
It enables the replacement of the internal message-dispatching procedure of the LStep API.

The LStep API processes during waiting for confirmation of the LStep in the main-thread messages. If you want to switch of the Message-Dispatching or replace with your onw Code, you can use SetProcessMessagesProc for using a callback-procedure.

pProc must be a pointer to a stdcall-procedure without a parameter:

```
void MyProcessMessages() {...}
```

Example:
LS.SetProcessMessagesProc(&MyProcessMessages);

**As example if we take python stdout, how I can send the message to it?**

Comment: If you load this dll into your own Python process, it must be feasible using ctypes module. Sorry no time to make an example right now. Typing from phone.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, this is my problem, I do not get what I should path to this function LS_SetProcessMessagesProc as a parameter using ctypes. If you can write some kind of example or explain in other words, what should be done, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to illustrate everything on the:

- [[MSDN]: EnumWindows function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) - which enumerates all windows on the screen, and for each of them calls a *callback* function - check next bullet
- [[MSDN]: EnumWindowsProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx) - which is used to handle every enumerated window

which is (a slightly more complicated example of) what you need: a function defined in an external *.dll* which needs to call another custom function (written by you in *Python*), via [[Python]: ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) (on *Win*).

The code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

try:
    from win32gui import GetWindowText
    pywin32_present = True
except ImportError:
    pywin32_present = False


def enum_windows_proc(hwnd, l_param):
    print("HWND: {}\n".format(hwnd))
    if pywin32_present:
        txt = GetWindowText(hwnd)
        if txt and "MSCTFIME UI" not in txt and "Default IME" not in txt:
            print("  Window text: {}\n".format(txt))
    return 1


def main():
    user32_dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    enum_windows = user32_dll.EnumWindows

    WND_ENUM_PROC_TYPE = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(wintypes.BOOL, wintypes.HWND, wintypes.LPARAM)
    enum_windows.argtypes = (WND_ENUM_PROC_TYPE, wintypes.LPARAM)
    enum_windows.restype = wintypes.BOOL

    enum_windows(WND_ENUM_PROC_TYPE(enum_windows_proc), wintypes.LPARAM(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- `import`s:

  - *wintypes* is a *ctypes* sub-module that defines a bunch of *Ms* specific data (constants, structs, enums, ...)
  - [[Python]: pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) is a *Python* wrapper over *C* *Win* functions, it's basically a more advanced (and pythonic) approach of what *ctypes* does. It doesn't come with *Python* by default, it must be manually installed; in our example, it's optional
- `def enum_windows_proc(hwnd, l_param):`:

  - It's the *Python* form of `BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ LPARAM lParam);`
  - Prints the *hwnd* (window handle) for each window (note that there will be lots of such windows, since most of them are "invisible" to the user)
  - If *pywin32* module is installed, it will be used to extract each window's title(caption). Of course, that can also be done with *ctypes* but it's a little bit more complicated
  - The title filtering is to avoid printing useless text (for most of the windows). If you want more details, check: [[SO]:
    Get the title of a window of another program using the process name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278590/get-the-title-of-a-window-of-another-program-using-the-process-name/31280850#31280850)
- The `main` function:

  - First, the *.dll* that contains the function (in our case *user32.dll*) needs to be loaded. This is done using [[MSDN]: LoadLibrary function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) (*Ux*: [[man]: dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)). Also, the internal structure (needed for next line to look so simple) of the returned object (`user32_dll`) is initialized
  - The function (or better: a pointer to it) is being retrieved (`enum_windows`) using [[MSDN]:
    GetProcAddress function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) (*Ux*: [[man]: dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html))
  - The next 3 lines of code are used to let *Python* know the details about the loaded function pointer (return type and argument types). Note that (in some cases) there is a simpler way (codewise) to do all that, but for learning purposes, it's OK to go through the whole thing
  - Finally, call the external function, with our custom function as an argument

Since there will be lots of output (and will be mostly memory addresses), I won't paste it here.

Going to your problem, based on the function headers you pasted in the question, we can take the same approach (note that the code will **not** work copy/pasted *OOTB*):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

def my_process_messages():
    # Your code here (delete the next (`pass`) line)
    pass

dll_name = "your dll path (full or relative)"
dll_object = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(dll_name)
ls_set_process_messages_proc = dll_object.LS_SetProcessMessagesProc

PROCESS_MESSAGES_TYPE = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None)
ls_set_process_messages_proc.argtypes = (PROCESS_MESSAGES_TYPE,)
ls_set_process_messages_proc.restype = ctypes.c_int

print("ls_set_process_messages_proc returned: {}\n".format(ls_set_process_messages_proc(PROCESS_MESSAGES_TYPE(my_process_messages))))
```

**Note**: The example is based on the fact that the external *.dll*:

- Is *Win* style (uses *stdcall* calling convention). If that's not true (it uses *cdecl*), you need to change (for rigorousity's sake I'm going to say 2 things):

  - `ctypes.windll` to `ctypes.cdll`
  - `ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE` to `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE`
- Exports *C* style functions (**not** *C++* which mangles function names), which I'm almost 100% sure. But, if this is not the case then, sorry, nothing to do here. For more details on this topic, check: [[SO]: Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124452/excel-vba-cant-find-dll-entry-point-from-a-dll-file).

Answer (score 1):

> Read about [ctypes tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries)
>       Loading-dynamic-link-libraries
>       Accessing functions from loaded dlls
>       Calling functions

Linux example there, which uses the standard C library's qsort function:

1. Load the `libc.so.6` dll.

   ```
   from ctypes import *
   libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
   ```
2. Get a function pointer to `qsort`.

   ```
   qsort = libc.qsort
   qsort.restype = None
   ```
3. Create the type for the callback function
   and  implement the `Python` callback function.

   ```
   CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int))

   def py_cmp_func(a, b):
       return a[0] - b[0]

   cmp_func = CMPFUNC(py_cmp_func)
   ```
4. Define a C-Type Integer Array with values
   and use `qsort` to sort the Array using `cmp_func`.

   ```
   IntArray5 = c_int * 5
   ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)

   qsort(ia, len(ia), sizeof(c_int), cmp_func)

   for i in ia:
       print(i)
   ```

> **Output**
>
> ```
> 1 5 7 33 99
> ```