# PROJECTNAME_EXPORT macro doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019 in DLL Project

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, dllexport

I create a DLL project.

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't define the MACRO HAZEL_EXPORTS (<ProjectName>_EXPORTS ). So I can't export/import my symbols.
Any Help?

Here is my code:

```
#pragma once


// test.h // Project name is Hazel
#ifdef HAZEL_EXPORTS
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif



namespace Hazel
{
    API void Print();

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIKgJ.png)

Comment: You are need to define `HAZEL_EXPORTS` in the project setting when exporting (building the DLL) and not define it when importing (using the DLL).  `Configuration Properties > C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`

Comment: Might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124452/excel-vba-cant-find-dll-entry-point-from-a-dll-file/44177222#44177222