# c++ how to link function declaration at runtime?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a function declaration inside my shared library (*.dll) and the definition is inside another application, here is a minimal code. but how to tell the compiler find the symbol `set_x` (inside the mylib.cpp) at run time after the library loaded to the application. the extern keyword search it at link time. or is there any other way to call a method defined in the application.cpp?

```
// mylib.cpp compiles to mylib.dll
class MyClass{
public:
    extern void set_x(int); // need to tell the compiler to search at runtime
}

extern "C"{
EXPORT_API void lib_func(MyClass* o){
    printf("setting o's x value");
    o->set_x(42);
}
}
```

```
// application.cpp compiles to application.exe
class MyClass{
private:
    int x = 0;
public:
    extern void set_x(int _x){ x = _x; }
}

typedef void (*func_ptr)(MyClass*);
...
func_ptr lib_func = (lib_func_ptr)dlopen_and_get_func_ptr("mydll.lib", "lib_func");
MyClass cls;
lib_func(&cls);
...
```

Comment: Normally, you would `link` to the binary which contained the implementation.  But you can't link to an executable.  That's what libraries are for.  Move the implementation into `mylib.dll` or into a new library and link both targets to it.

Comment: when an application using some functions from a library they must be defined inside the library but here the shared library need access to some function inside the application, and the shared library is like a script which could load and unload at runtime. @Stewart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you're mixing *C* and *C++* concepts. Even if the 2<sup>nd</sup> was built on top of the 1<sup>st</sup>, they have very different ways of dealing with this situation. I'm going to ficus on *C++*. 
However, no matter which approach is to be chosen there are some things that are wrong in the code:

- *MyClass* definition appears twice **and differs** (also - personal remark - I find names that start with "*My*", brain scratching)
- The class is not exported

*dll00.h*:

```c
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(DLL00_EXPORTS)
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


class DLL00_EXPORT_API BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void setX(int x) = 0;  // Pure virtual
    // Some other method declarations might go here. Their implementation should be in dll00.cpp
};


DLL00_EXPORT_API void callSetX(BaseClass *pClass, int value);
```

*dll00.cpp*:

```c
#define DLL00_EXPORTS
#include "dll00.h"

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;


void callSetX(BaseClass *pClass, int value) {
    if (!pClass) {
        cout << "NULL pointer!\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "Setting x\n";
    pClass->setX(value);
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```c
#include "dll00.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;


class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    void setX(int x) override;

private:
    int x;
};


void DerivedClass::setX(int x) {
    std::cout << "setX(" << x << ")\n";
    this->x = x;
}


int main() {
    DerivedClass *pInst = new DerivedClass;
    callSetX(pInst, 255);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061152778]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> **********************************************************************
> ** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.21
> ** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> **********************************************************************
> [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> dll00.h
> main.cpp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL /EHsc dll00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.cpp
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /EHsc main.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /OUT:main.exe dll00.lib
> main.cpp
>    Creating library main.lib and object main.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> dll00.cpp
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.h
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
> main.cpp
> main.exe
> main.exp
> main.lib
> main.obj
>
> [prompt]> main.exe
> Setting x
> setX(255)
> ```

For more details on exporting stuff from *.dll*s, you could check [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581837/linker-error-when-calling-a-c-function-from-c-code-in-different-vs2010-project/30583411#30583411).

**Note**: On *Nix*, I've often seen this behavior (in *C*): an *.so* referencing symbols defined in the executable that loads it (one such example is static *Python* (where the core is in the executable), and the symbols are referenced by the *extension modules*), but on *Win* (at least *VStudio* compiler) this is not possible.