# How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, openssl

I am having a hard time trying to add openssl to my project. I have downloaded the precompiled installer for windows, and I have the libraries installed, but I can't find a way to include openssl in my project.

Note: I am using Visual Studio Expres 2012 on Windows 7 x64, but it's not restricted to that environment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Intro

- Although the question / answer is based on:

  - *OpenSSL 1.0.1**
  - *VStudio 2012*

  it applies to **any** *OpenSSL* version (*v.0.9.**, *v1.**, *v3.**, ...), and **any** *VStudio* version (*v2005*+)
- *OpenSSL* builds are also available at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/OpenSSL](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/OpenSSL)** (check [[SO]: How to install OpenSSL in windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60051023/4788546) for more details)

---

Let's assume you have installed *OpenSSL* in a *dir* like: *"C:\Program Files\Openssl-Win32-1.0.1p....."* (or whatever other name); I am going to refer to that as *OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR* (as it was an *Nix* style *env* *var*). So, *${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}* should contain a bunch of *dir*s and files, out of which matter for us:

- *Dir*s:

  - *include*
  - *lib*
- Files (since their names vary across versions, I'm going to refer to them using (again, *Nix* style *var*) placeholders; also they might be located in a ***bin*** *subdir*):

  1. *${LIBCRYPTO}.dll*
  2. *${LIBSSL}.dll*

  where ***LIBCRYPTO*** (*#1.*) and ***LIBSSL*** (*#2.*) are defined as follows:

  - *v1.0.2* and older

    1. *libeay32*
    2. *ssleay32* (might be also copied (or *symlink*ed) to *libssl32*)
  - *v1.1.**

    1. *libcrypto-1_*(-x64)*
    2. *libssl-1_*(-x64)*
  - *v3.**

    1. *libcrypto-3*(-x64)*
    2. *libssl-3*(-x64)*

As a side note, on *Nix*, the 2 files (*.dll*s - shared objects) are typically named *libcrypto.so.** and *libssl.so.** (where suffix is a version indicator).

In order to make use of *OpenSSL* installation, in your *VStudio* project you have to (check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546) for more details on the rationale (the **why** part)):

##### 1. Configure the compiler ([[MS.Learn]: Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/fwkeyyhe(v=vs.110)))

Instruct it:

- **Where** to search for include (header (*.h*)) files. Go to your "*Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories*" and adding ***${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}\include*** (if you need to add other paths, separate them by a semicolon (***;***)). Now you can include in your source code *OpenSSL* header files. 
  Note that because "*${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}\include*" *dir* contains an *openssl* subdir and under that subdir are the actual header files, your *#include* clauses would have to look like this:

  ```c
  #include <openssl/ssl.h>
  ```

  Of course you could add *${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}\include\openssl* *dir* to your project, and then the above include statement would be:

  ```c
  #include <ssl.h>
  ```

  but the former is preferred (recommended)

##### 2. Configure the linker ([[MS.Learn]: Linker Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/y0zzbyt4(v=vs.110)))

Instruct it:

- **Where** to search for libraries. You can do that by going to your "*Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories*" and adding ***${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}\lib*** (again, if there are multiple paths, separate them by ***;***)
- **What** libraries to use. "*${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}\lib*" *dir* contains a bunch of *.lib* files. Out of those, you will (most likely) only need ***${LIBCRYPTO}.lib*** and / or ***${LIBSSL}.lib***. Go to your "*Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies*" and add those 2 libraries next to the existing ones

  - For each of the 2 libraries, there are 2 variants:

    1. The "normal" one
    2. Another one ending in "*_static*" ***<sup>(1)</sup>***

    Check [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MS Visual C (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118400/4788546) (at the beginning) for a brief explanation of each

##### 3. Build and run

Now, if all your settings and source code are correct, you should have a "buildable" project. When you'll want to **run** your project output (either an *.exe* or a *.dll* needed by another executable), the executable will need to find the 2 *.dll*s that I mentioned at the beginning (**if you linked with the *_static* versions (check <sup>#1</sup>), this doesn't apply (isn't required)**). For that, you should **either**:

1. Add their *dir* to your *PATH* *env* *var* (**I consider this the cleanest one**). Example:

   - From console (before launching the executable):

     ```bat
     set PATH=%PATH%;${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
     ```
   - For the running *VStudio* instance:

     [image: Img0]
2. Copy them in the folder where your executable is located ([[MS.Learn]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order))
3. Copy them in one of the *dir*s from your *%PATH%*.
   Some installers might copy the 2 *.dll*s in your "*%SystemRoot%\System32*" *dir*, and in that case this will no longer be necessary (**I find this practice of copying stuff in system *dir*s a bad one**, as in our current example multiple versions can ship the same file names, and the last one installed would overwrite all the others)

**Important note**: Must be careful when targeting your project for *032bit* or *064bit* (setting *Platform* to *Win32* or *x64* in *VStudio IDE*) - that has to match your *OpenSSL* installation architecture (check [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) for (funky) errors that occur if it doesn't).

Worth mentioning that *.dll* search mechanism also applies when the *.dll* is dynamically loaded (via [[MS.Learn]: LoadLibraryExW function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) functions family), as explained in the above *URL*. There are also other ways (but those include hardocding paths: [[MS.Learn]: AddDllDirectory function (libloaderapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory)). Although in a more complex scenario, [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546) covers them.

Comment: Fantastic Answer. VS2019...but more so these little hidden settings I dont explore often are nice to learn bout

Answer (score 7):

A lot has changed since this question was originally asked.  Since then `vcpkg` has come along and has made installing external libraries a lot easier.

To install and use vcpkg, use the following:

```
git clone  https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg integrate install
```

The last command is for optional, but recommended User-wide integration.

Then to install OpenSsl, try the following:

```
vcpkg search ssl
vcpkg install openssl-windows --triplet x64-windows
```

Your options may vary depending on the platform specifics.

Restart Visual Studio and you should be ready to go.

Tested with Visual Studio Community 2019.

References:

[vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

[vcpkg Quick Start](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Conan. It is very simple to install and use:

[www.conan.io](https://www.conan.io/)

You can request the files ready for use. For example for Linux x64 or usage with Visual Studio 2012... Here a sample instruction:

```
conan install OpenSSL/1.0.2g@lasote/stable -s arch="x86_64" -s build_type="Debug" -s compiler="gcc" -s compiler.version="5.3" -s os="Linux" -o 386="False" -o no_asm="False" -o no_rsa="False" -o no_cast="False" -o no_hmac="False" -o no_sse2="False" -o no_zlib="False" ...
```

Comment: use vcpkg           its like yum for centos    `vcpkg install openssl-windows`

Comment: (2 commands you need to run in this order)
`vcpkg integrate install`
`vcpkg install openssl-windows`
first command auto installs packages into the proper locations of your VC2017/VC2019