# How to specify the directory to store the.pdb and import library file being created when building a .dll in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build

I specified Linker->General->Output File for my target .dll file. I wanted the corresponding .pdb and import .lib to be created in the same folder, but they weren't. How can I achieve that?

=========================================================================
I've just found that. In Project Property->Linker->Debugging, pdb file can be set, and in Project Property->Linker->Advanced, import library can.

However, because I changed the location for the import library, building another project in the same solution would get an error saying it cannot open that import library. So now I need to find out how to specify the location of an import library which is needed as an input.

Answer (score 1):

For the 1<sup>st</sup> project (let's call it ***producer***), you changed the import library (*producer.lib*) path from (for simplicity's sake, let's say):

- *C:\old_path*

to:

- *C:\new_path*

So far so good, *producer* project builds, and *producer.lib* is placed in *C:\new_path*.

But there's another project (let's call it ***consumer***) that looks for *producer.lib* in *C:\old_path*. Obviously, the *.lib* is not there and *consumer* build fails. To fix that, you have to update the paths where *consumer* is looking for *lib*s, and change them as you did for *producer*. 
In order to do that, go in *consumer*'s properties under *Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories* and replace *C:\old_path* by *C:\new_path*.

Here's [[MS.Docs]: /LIBPATH (Additional Libpath)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/libpath-additional-libpath) for future reference.

You could also check [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio/32158521#32158521) for more details on this topic.

Note that other projects in the solution could be in the same situation.