# jwt-cpp library LNK2019 Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, jwt

I am trying to create, validate, and get data from a jwt token using C++.
The library I choose is [jwt-cpp](https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp) because I found it easy to use and it supports almost every algorithm.

For the setup, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156336/how-to-include-openssl-in-visual-studio).

- Configured the compiler: Added installed openssl include folder path
  [image: Added installed openssl include folder path]

Additionally, there is another path for using jwt-cpp library.

- Configure the linker: Setting installed openssl lib folder to linker->general
  [image: Setting installed openssl lib folder to linker->general]
  Setting libcrypto and libssl lib to linker->input
  [image: Setting libcrypto and libssl lib to linker->input]
- Copying libcrypto and libssl dll to executable folder
  [image: Copying libcrypto and libssl dll to executable folder]

After that, while following the basic tutorial in the [jwt-cpp link](https://github.com/Thalhammer/jwt-cpp),
I can read all claims and header from the token.

But, when I try to execute token verification or creation (as code provided in the link), I get LNK2019

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _HMAC referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall jwt::algorithm::hmacsha::sign(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::error_code &)const " (?sign@hmacsha@algorithm@jwt@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV45@AAVerror_code@5@@Z)
```

and

```
>Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _HMAC referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall jwt::algorithm::hmacsha::sign(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::error_code &)const " (?sign@hmacsha@algorithm@jwt@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV45@AAVerror_code@5@@Z)
```

I can guess that the issue can be in linker setup. I also found a lot of versions of libcrypto and libssl like libcrypto64MD, libcrypto64MDd libcrypto64MT, libcrypto64MTd, libssl64MD, libssl64MDd libssl64MT, libssl64MTd.

Can anybody tell me what can be the issue here?

Comment: The screenshots indicate that you made the changes in the Debug Win32 configuration, but then you show the 64-bit crypto/ssl DLLs. Make sure you edit the configuration(s) that you actually want to build, and you use the matching bitness for the LIBs and DLLs.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv , this was the issue. I changed everything to x64 arch and everything is working fine now.