# How do I include 'cfitsio' in C?

Tags: c, dll

First of all, I am sorry that I am not familiar with English.

I want to use the fits file in C.(in Dev C++)
So I downloaded cfitsio 4.2.0.zip and decompressed it. And as a result of following the README.win, I got several files including cfitsio.dll, cfitsio.exp, and cfitsio.lib in the release folder.

but problome... I don't know how apply this file...

What can I do?

I tried,

1. Put all the cfitsio files before building into the include file
2. Put in Linker that dll, lib, exp files.
   -> all fail, #include "fitsio.h" showed an error.

I'm sorry. I might look stupid.
thank you.

Comment: What you include in your c file is the .h file.  Then link with the .lib file. Then have the .dll file in the correct directory when you run. Correct dir depends on Windows version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I completed, I tried this.
I use Visual Studio instead of Dev C++, however, maybe it work same in Dev C++, I didn't do that.

1. I follow this guid, https://eteo.tistory.com/348
2. I Put in dll file in repos folder(place exsiting .c file)

Work! I am happy