# How to resolve linking error in C Python API

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am getting a linking error in my Visual Studio C project. Those are related to external functions of C-Python API not being resolved in the linking stage. One of them being: `unresolved external symbol __ipm_Py_Finalize referenced in function _main`
I Have Added the library folder of Python in the Linker Additional Library Directory and added include folder in C/C++ Additional Include Directory. Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_Initialze();
    printf("Initialized python interpreter!");
    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("CPBridger");
    if (module == NULL) {
        printf("Can't find module!");
        return -1;
    }

    PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "helloWorld");
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(0);
    PyObject_CallObject(func, args);

    Py_XDECREF(func);
    Py_XDECREF(args);

    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "sayHelloTo");
    args = PyTuple_Pack(1, PyString_FromString("LakshyaK2011"));
    PyObject_CallObject(func, args);

    Py_XDECREF(func);
    Py_XDECREF(args);
    Py_XDECREF(module);

    Py_Finalize();
    printf("Finalized python interpreter!");
}
```

What shall I configure in VS to make it resolve the external references?

Comment: Are you sure you have ```python.h``` in your C++ path as with ```#include <Python.h>```? Perhaps you can provide its address like ```#include "address/of/Python.h"```

Comment: I have included python include, compiling is fine, but when Linking, error comes up!
Note: Its C actually, not C++

Comment: If there is the ```DLL``` file available, make its address available to the linker as well.

Comment: It is not enough to add a library folder, you need to specify which libraries to use.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please add link command and its (full) output. You also need to add *python3\*.lib* in the dependencies section. [\[SO\]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546) contains an example for *OpenSSL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in this secnario, I haven't included python3.lib, Simple fix to this is to iinclude python3.lib in the Linker.