# How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, dllimport, dllexport, libjpeg

I want to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b. According to the document [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx), it seems that we need to add a preprocessor `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)`   before the declaration of each function to be exported, in addition to setting the Configuration Type to "Dynamic Library (.dll)". But this is not an easy job because there are so many functions in libjpeg. So, is there any short-cut or work-around to build a DLL libjpeg without or with little modification of the jpeglib.h? Is there any DLL-ready source of libjpeg 9b available? I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 64bit. Thanks for your answer.

PS: I downloaded the source of libjpeg 9b from http://www.ijg.org/files/. Is this the official place to download it? I ask because the beginning bytes of .vcxproj (originally .v10) files seems invalid (C2 8B C2 AF C2 A8) so Visual Studio is unable to open it.

Comment: You want to build it from _VStudio14.0_ IDE or you just want to build it using _VStudio14.0_ tools?

Comment: @CristiFati: It doesn't matter. My purpose is just to save memory consumption by building libjpeg as a dll because there are more than one 3rd-party libraries using it on my machine. My concern is how to avoid manually adding __declspec(dllexport) or __declspec(dllimport) before each function. It should be possible because I saw many 3rd-party libraries produce dll while I cannot find any __declspec(dllexport) or __declspec(dllimport) in their sources. I'm curious how they made it.

Comment: Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Published builds (static / dynamic) on **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/LibJPEG](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/LibJPEG)**.

---

Like almost all of the nowadays software, *LibJPEG* is also hosted on [[GitHub]: winlibs/libjpeg - libjpeg-9b](https://github.com/winlibs/libjpeg/releases/tag/libjpeg-9b). I downloaded it from both places, did a comparison and only few minor differences (out of which none in the source code) popped up. I'm going to explain on the *GitHub* version. Unfortunately, there is no walkthrough on this, so I had to look inside some of the files in order to figure out what has to be done. Here's a list of steps:

### 1. Prepare the ground

1<sup>st</sup> thing is to extract the compressed (*.zip* / *.tar.gz*) file content into a folder (and have a *Cmd* console opened there). That folder contains a bunch of files. The 1<sup>st</sup> one that we need is *makefile.vc*. As it name suggests, it's a *Makefile* that consists of a series of rules/instructions used in general to build stuff.

As a remark, I'm using ***VStudio (Community) 2015*** (*14*) for this task (but there should be no differences for newer versions).

The tool that deals with *Makefile*s is *NMake* ([[MS.Docs]: NMAKE reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/nmake-reference?view=vs-2015)). We need to call it against that file. *NMake* is located in "*${VSTUDIO_INSTALL_DIR}\VC\bin\nmake.exe*" (the (*Nix* style) *env var* doesn't really exist, it's just a path placeholder); typically that is "*%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"* (e.g. on my machine it's *"C:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\VC\bin\nmake.exe*").

Note that when dealing with *VStudio* command line tools, it's better to either:

- Use ***VCVarsAll*** (that's a (*batch*) tool that sets some *env var*s like *%PATH%*, *%INCLUDE%*, *%LIB%*, ...), so all the *VStudio* tools are available without their full path. But since it's also located in "*%VSTUDIO_INSTALL_DIR%\VC\vcvarsall.bat*" (check [[SO]: Linking to CRT (unresolved external symbol WinMainCRTStartup) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71872682/4788546) for more details), it doesn't worth the effort to locate / call it
- Use *VS2015 Tools Command Prompt* from *Start Menu* (which basically calls *VCVarsAll*)
- [[MS.Docs]: Building on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2015) contains more details on this topic

Now that we know where *NMake* is located, let's run:

```bat
"${VSTUDIO_INSTALL_DIR}\VC\bin\nmake.exe" /f makefile.vc setup-v10
```

(don't forget to enclose *NMake*'s path in *DblQuotes*(**"**), especially if it contains *SPACE*s).

If running into issues, *Google* will probably yield solutions:

- One very likely to be encountered: ***fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found*** - check [[SO]: Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546)

*setup-v10* is a *Makefile target*, which simply renames some of the files in the folder (frankly, I don't know why the files aren't like already renamed in the 1<sup>st</sup> place).

After running the command in the folder, there should be 2 *VStudio* solution files:

- *jpeg.sln* - which contains one project:

  - *jpeg.vcxproj* - this is the project responsible of building the lib
- *apps.sln* - which contains a bunch of projects (which I don't know/care what they do):

  - *djpeg.vcxproj* - this is the only one that I'm going to mention, since I'll be using it to test the built lib

### 2. Build the *jpeg* library

The 1<sup>st</sup> thing to notice is that the solution / project files generated in the previous section are for *VStudio 2010*. But that's not a problem, since *VStudio 2015* is able to handle them (when loading them, it will do all the necessary conversions to bring them up to date).

Opening *jpeg.sln*, will reveal some (unpleasant) stuff about the solution (and project):

- It only has *Win32* (32bit or *x86*) platform

  - It only has *Release* configuration
- As you already mentioned, it builds a static library

Anyway, the solution should build *OOTB*. After completion, you'd notice a *Release* folder which should contain (besides a bunch of intermediary - *.obj* files), a **4+ MB** *jpeg.lib* file which is the static *.lib*. Knowing that the code (and project related files) is OK, let's move on to the next step.

#### 2.1 Build the *jpeg* *.dll*

In order to avoid breaking existing functionality, we should create a **new configuration** (note that the process of creating a new **platform** for your project is (almost) the same):

- From menu, choose *Build -> Configuration Manager...*
- In the dialog box that popped, up click on the *Release* combo box and select *< New...>*
- In the *New Solution Configuration* dialog box, select a name for the new configuration: I chose *Release-DLL* (and from now on I'm going to rely on this name)
- Make sure to select *Release* in the *Copy settings from* combo-box
- Check *Create new project configurations*

After pressing *OK*, the new the *Release-DLL* configuration will be identical to *Release*. Next step is to do the necessary changes to it, in order to achieve our goal. *RClick* on the *jpeg* project in the *Solution Explorer* (in the left side of *VStudio* window), and choose *Properties*:

[image: VStudio settings]

In the image above, there's the *jpeg* project settings window, showing how they should look like at the end. I highlighted (using colors) different points of interest:

- Blue: the *Platform* / *Configuration* pair:

  - That is being modified (in the topmost dialog box)
  - Active (in the *VStudio* main window in the back)

  When modifying some *Platform* / *Configuration* settings **make sure that it's the active one** (the data in the blue rectangles is identical), otherwise you'd bang your head against the walls and waste time trying to figure out why something that seems correct, doesn't work as expected. On my opinion, when this dialog box pops up, it should have the *active* values, but that's not always the case.
- Red: items that **should** be modified (or at least require attention):

  - *Configuration Type* should obviously be *Dynamic Library (.dll)*
  - *Platform Toolset* should be *Visual Studio 2015* (I'm mentioning this, since it happened to open a *VStudio 2010* project with *VStudio2015*, and it kept the old toolset, and continued to build with it, but that's only if you have both versions installed)
- Green: items recommended to be modified. Those are only folders. Notice the *$(Platform)* variable (that I use as a good practice), which comes in handy when building for more than 1 platform (e.g. *Win32* and *x64*)

*Save All* and build. After the build succeeds, a new folder *Win32-Release-DLL* will appear, and like the previous one, it will contain a bunch of files **plus** *jpeg.dll*. One might think that it's done, but it's not quite so. All the code is **compiled/built** in the *.dll*, but it's **not exported**, so the *.dll* is pretty much unusable. You can check many of *.dll* (or *.exe*) properties opening it with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) (or newer [[GitHub]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)). You can look at the screenshots from [[SO]: Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177222/4788546) - in our case the export area will be empty.

**One final note**: If you think that in the future you'll need to build for other platforms (*x64*, or even *ARM*), and also you'll need to do some debugging (add a *Debug* configuration), add the *Debug* configuration under *Win32* platform **first**, and **only then** create the new platform from *Win32*, otherwise you'll need to add the *Debug* configuration for every platform created before adding the *Debug* configuration to *Win32*.

#### 2.2 Export data from the *.dll*

Just as a note: besides the ***__declspec(dllexport)*** approach, there are 2 more (when dealing with exports from *Win* *.dll*s):

- Pass the export list as arguments to the linker ([[MS.Docs]: /EXPORT (Exports a Function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=vs-2015))
- Enumerate them in [[MS.Docs]: Module-Definition Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms925051(v=msdn.10))

But, since we don't know the code and there might be many symbols to export, neither one of the 3 is scalable (they would probably require lots of research / work). Anyway, we'll stick to the original approach:

1. **Save the following piece of code:**

   ```c
   #pragma once

   #if defined(_WIN32)
   #  if defined(LIBJPEG_STATIC)
   #    define LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API
   #  else
   #    if defined(LIBJPEG_EXPORTS)
   #      define LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
   #    else
   #      define LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #    endif
   #  endif
   #else
   #  define LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API
   #endif
   ```

   in a file called *jexport.h* in the *libjpeg* source folder. This is a pretty standard header file that deals with *.dll* exports.
   Next, add it to the project: in *Solution Explorer*, *RClick* on *Header Files -> Add -> Existing Item...*
2. **Make use of the new file**

   ```diff
   --- jmorecfg.h.orig 2016-03-30 09:38:56.000000000 +0300
   +++ jmorecfg.h  2017-06-09 21:04:33.762535400 +0300
   @@ -30,6 +30,8 @@
     * in all cases (see below).
     */

   +#include "jexport.h"
   +
    #define BITS_IN_JSAMPLE  8 /* use 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12 */


   @@ -245,7 +247,8 @@
    /* a function referenced thru EXTERNs: */
    #define GLOBAL(type)       type
    /* a reference to a GLOBAL function: */
   -#define EXTERN(type)       extern type
   +
   +#define EXTERN(type)       extern LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API type


    /* This macro is used to declare a "method", that is, a function pointer.
   ```

   The above is a *diff*. See [[SO]: Run/Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *utrunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with  **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with  **one "-"** sign goes out). But, since the changes are trivial, they can also be done manually. The file that needs to be changed, is *jmorecfg.h* (2 things are required):

   - Include the new file at the beginning (`#include "jexport.h"`)
   - Modify line 251 (replace `#define EXTERN(type)        extern type` by `#define EXTERN(type)       extern LIBJPEG_EXPORT_API type`)

   I consider this step some kind of a workaround (*gainarie*), but as I stated, the "real thing" would simply require too much work (and time).
3. **Tell the *compiler* to take our changes into account**

   Edit the project settings (again be careful with *Platform* / *Configuration*), select *Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions* and replace the old value (in my case: *WIN32;NDEBUG;_LIB;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS*) to *WIN32;LIBJPEG_EXPORTS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;NDEBUG*. What I did was:

   1. **Adding** *LIBJPEG_EXPORTS*
   2. **Removing** *_LIB*
   3. Some shifting

   [[MS.Docs]: /D (Preprocessor Definitions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=vs-2015) might contain some useful info.

   As a **side note**, after the above changes, the original (or "normal") behavior (*Release* configuration) will not be *OK* (it will build with a bunch of warnings, but that's not correct technically). That is because I didn't want to rely on the *_LIB* macro to differentiate between the static / dynamic library build. To straighten things out, **add *LIBJPEG_STATIC* in the *Preprocessor Definitions* for *Release* configuration** (following the same procedure as above).

*Save All* and build. After the build succeeds, the *jpeg.dll* is overwritten, and what's more important: **a new file *jpeg.lib* will be created; that tells us that *jpeg.dll* exports something**. You can check it again with *Dependency Walker*.

### 3. Test the *.dll*

- This is optional, I did it to be sure that what I did so far, was not in vain
- By tests, I only refer to building and running, meaning that I don't do any *functional testing* (the functions exported from the *.dll* actually do whatever they're supposed to)

Load the *apps.sln* solution, preferably in a new *VStudio* instance. As I said, I only care about the *djpeg* project.

1. 1<sup>st</sup> thing to do, is to build it for the existing *Release* configuration. But, because of the changes done to *jpeg* library, it won't build *OOTB* (there will be *linker* errors). In order to get rid of them, edit its settings, the *Preprocessor Definitions* (just like in the previous step), and add *LIBJPEG_STATIC* (don't forget the separator (**;**)).

   The build should be successful and under *djpeg\Release* folder, there should be a *djpeg.exe* file. Attempting to run it, will succeed (and this is the only thing I care about).
2. Build a new executable that uses our *.dll*:

   - Just like in *jpeg* library's case, create a new configuration: *Release-DLL* (make sure to do all the steps, but don't change it)
   - There's only one change required: let the *linker* know where we built our *.lib* file. Go to project settings, *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies*: the 1<sup>st</sup> is *Release\jpeg.lib*. Obviously, the path is not correct, so we need to replace *Release* by *Win32-Release-DLL* (of course you could use *VStudio* macros (for *Platform* / *Configuration*)). Might check [[MS.Docs]: .Lib Files as Linker Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input?view=vs-2015).

*Save All* and build. After the build succeeds, under *djpeg\Release-DLL*, there should be a *djpeg.exe* file. Attempting to run it will **fail**, since it can't find *jpeg.dll*. Fix that by either copying *jpeg.dll* to (check [[MS.Docs]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) for the semantics):

- The *djpeg.exe*'s folder
- One of the folders that's in the *%PATH%* *env var* (or the other way around, append the *jpeg.dll* folder to *%PATH%*)

Again, you can check the 2 executables with *Dependency Walker* (but the size difference says enough: the 2<sup>nd</sup> *djpeg.exe* is significantly smaller), to see which one depends on the *jpeg.dll*. Anyway, here's the output on my computer (yes, *Dependency Walker* can act as a *CmdLine* as well :) ):

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b>"c:\Install\x86\Depends\Dependency Walker-politist-texan\AllVers\depends.exe" /c /ot:static.txt djpeg\Release\djpeg.exe
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b>"c:\Install\x86\Depends\Dependency Walker-politist-texan\AllVers\depends.exe" /c /ot:dynamic.txt djpeg\Release-DLL\djpeg.exe
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b>type static.txt | findstr -i "jpeg.dll"
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b>type dynamic.txt | findstr -i "jpeg.dll"
>      [   ] e:\work\dev\stackoverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b\djpeg\release-dll\JPEG.DLL
> [   ]  e:\work\dev\stackoverflow\q044450813\src\libjpeg-libjpeg-9b\djpeg\release-dll\JPEG.DLL   2017-06-09 21:16  2017-06-09 21:16    237,056  A      0x00000000     0x0003ECC8     x86  GUI        CV,Unknown  0x10000000      Unknown      0x0003E000    Not Loaded  N/A              N/A              0.0        14.0        6.0     6.0
> ```

---

#### Update *#0*

I've also:

- Submitted the changes to **[[GitHub]: winlibs/libjpeg - Win: build libjpeg as a dll](https://github.com/winlibs/libjpeg/pull/3)** (rejected)
- Tried to contact [JPEG Reference](https://jpegclub.org/reference) (several times), but the form froze after hitting *SEND* (left it even overnight with no luck)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. What I learnt is the macro of EXTERN(type) that adds the __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) in one strike. I checked other 3rd-party libraries like zlib and found that it is the same technique used there. But libtiff seems not use this method. I don't know how they exported functions in the tiff.dll.

Comment: As I specified in my answer, another option of exporting stuff from *.dll*s is via __Module Definition Files__. Just downloaded _libtiff_ and found _libtiff\libtiff.def_.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for the help and useful information!

Comment: I went through the tutorial just fine (thank you!), but the DLL doesn't link properly in the first test. It gives me error `LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Release\jpeg.lib'` even though I've added `JPEG_STATIC` to preprocessor definitions. What did I miss?

Comment: @Draex_ (sorry, I posted this comment 3 months ago, but I forgot to explicitly add your ID so you are notified): You should use the new path: *"Win32-Release-DLL\\jpeg.lib"* as stated in one of the bullets of section 3 (if you want to use the dynamic version). Check where is the lib built, and add that folder. Maybe you're building for *Debug*?

Comment: I'm getting the error `makefile.vc(11) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found` running the command `nmake /f makefile.vc setup-10`.

Comment: @Barracuda: Did you run all the previous steps as I indicated? Also what *VStudio* version are you using? Also, did you install *Windows SDK*?

Comment: I found the solution. You must run `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"` from a `cmd` consul and if you face `makefile.vc(11) : fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found` error you must run `set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include;`

Comment: @moki: I studied the problem you were encountering in detail (and added a reference into the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546.