# Find all modules with a dependency on a specific DLL

Tags: visual-studio, dll, dependency-walker

I know I can use tools like Dependency Walker (and newer rewrites) to answer the question "what DLL dependencies does X have?"

But I have about 100 modules built in our solution, and from years ago `zlib.dll` is added into our release. I want to find out which (if any) of our modules require this old DLL without running dependency walker on each.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Why *"without running dependency walker on each"*? You can run it in command line (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450813/how-to-build-a-dll-version-of-libjpeg-9b/44469099#44469099 at the end) which makes it easy to automate. Do you only want the direct dependents or the whole tree?

Comment: I didn't realise that, maybe the answer is as simple as that if I can easily dump into a file to search. I think I need to consider indirect dependents because I know zlib is used by a lot of other 3rd-party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done by writing a script (a bat file, or PowerShell script) that enumerates all your module DLLs and uses [CLI of dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm).

The command line, that prints all dependent modules for a DLL looks like this:
./depends.exe /pl:1 /oc:./depends.csv ./depends.dll

And then simple text search within the file to find the zlib.dll in the output CSV.

File enumeration can be done as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell).