# make command in windows 10 generating the error:

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

Here's the code, I am trying to compile using make command in command prompt.

```
nvcc := "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc"
cudalib := "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
cudainclude := "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/include"
tensorflow := C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64

TF_CFLAGS := $$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') 
TF_LFLAGS := $$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') 


all: tf_nndistance_so.so
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.so
.PHONY : all clean

tf_nndistance_so.so: tf_nndistance_g.o tf_nndistance.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_nndistance.cpp tf_nndistance_g.o -o tf_nndistance_so.so -fPIC $(TF_CFLAGS) $(TF_LFLAGS) -O2

tf_nndistance_g.o: tf_nndistance_g.cu
    $(nvcc) -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -c -o tf_nndistance_g.o tf_nndistance_g.cu -I $(tensorflow) -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -O2
```

But getting the following error:

```
"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.0/bin/nvcc" -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -c -o tf_nndistance_g.o tf_nndistance_g.cu -I C:/"Program Files (x86)"/"Microsoft Visual Studio"/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64 -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -O2
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
make: *** [Makefile:19: tf_nndistance_g.o] Error 1
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Is cl.exe in your path? Have you tried using a visual studio command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

**The immediate problem**

You need to set your *VStudio* (*2019* that you already have installed) paths.

A common way of doing that is invoking *vcvarsall.bat*: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64`. 
More details on building from command line: [[SO]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450813/how-to-build-a-dll-version-of-libjpeg-9b/44469099#44469099).

**The bigger problem**

You are mixing compilers:

- *CUDA Toolkit* uses (by default) *VStudio* (native) compiler (***cl.exe***)
- You are using ***g++.exe***

This is a bad idea you should stick to one compiler (*cl* - as instructed in previous section). Note that some flags that you use are not compatible. 
Or instruct *CUDA* to use *g++* (don't know what build toolchain it belongs to, and **don't know if possible**).

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio.

You will need to add the folder containing the "cl.exe" file to your path environment variable. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
```

go to `My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`. Here look for "`PATH`" in the list, and add the path above (or whatever is the location of your cl.exe).