# Python ctypes cannot load Debug dll but can load Release one

Tags: python, c++, debugging, dll, ctypes

I have a c++ dll project in Visual Studio 2022, that is meant to be called from python with ctypes. However, while the release DLL loads fine, the debug one cant be found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\RECURSIVE_NODES\python\gym_cartpole.py", line 25, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'c:\...\RECURSIVE_NODES\x64\Debug\RECURSIVE_NODES.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

The DLL exists, and the path is correct, I have checked it 10 times over. It just wont work. Python code is as follows :

```
from pathlib import Path
dll_path = 'c:\...\RECURSIVE_NODES\x64\Debug\RECURSIVE_NODES.dll'
sPath = Path(dll_path)
print(sPath.is_file())  # returns true for both release and debug DLLs , so the file exists and is found by pathlib !!
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)
```

The ellipsis in the path omit irrelevant parts of it. When I replace "Debug" with "Release" in the above path, the dll is correctly loaded. Whats the problem here ?

SOLUTION

As @MarkTolonen said in the comments, “Or one of its dependencies”. I checked those in the developper command prompt with *dumpbin /dependents RECURSIVE_NODES.dll*, and one of the differences between Release and Debug was the Adress Sanitizer's dll. For some reason Visual Studio was not able to find it, even though I was using its own debugger. Thats not the first time aSan has caused me troubles, so I disabled it, recompiled and python now finds the dll.

Comment: Does that happen on the computer you developed the *.dll* (with *VStudio* installed)?

Comment: “Or one of its dependencies”

Comment: @CristiFati yes. RECURSIVE_NODES is the vs solution.

Comment: *OK*, what if you launch *Python* from the *VStudio* console (if you don;t know how, check [\[SO\]: How to build a DLL version of libjpeg 9b? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469099/4788546) *Prepare the ground* section)? For more debugging, check [\[SO\]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)

Comment: @CristiFati that's what I am doing already, I tried both running from VS and from python dllUser.py in the command line. Sorry I should have mentioned it.  I found the problem, editing my post to add the answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen can you please remove the [duplicate] mark ? (I assume you are the one who flagged it because you also answered the question linked in the duplicate notice) I cannot currently ask questions on the site because too many were flagged as dupes. I think this one is not a dupe, even though it has the same answer as the question you linked. Mine is between Release and Debug DLLs in ctype, the other between python and c++. Moreso, the problem here is that visual studio cant find its own adress sanitizer dll, not that I forgot one I manually added.  I believe this question adds value.