# Creating a DLL using MSVC's cl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, cl

I am attempting to get an understanding of how building and linking works, since there's a library I want to compile into a DLL. I do not have control over the tool that will be used to compile - It's going to be the `msvc` tools invoked via command line.

To that end, I've managed to locate [a tutorial on creating DLLs that does not use Visual Studio](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/). it's for `mingw`, but I've managed to make it work with `cl`

I've managed to translate part of the process to use with the `msvc` tools:

```
gcc -c -o add.o add.c -D ADD_EXPORTS
```

was translated into

```
cl /c /D ADD_EXPORTS add.c
```

I was unable to fully translate the line that follows:

```
gcc -o add.dll add.o -s -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

But the following worked:

```
link /DLL /NOENTRY add.obj
```

and created `.exp`, `.lib`, and `.dll` files. The `-s` switch doesn't seem important (it strips some info, so I'm guessing at worst I'll get a slightly larger file)

I then managed to create a `.obj` file from `addtest.c`, link it (against the `.lib` file), and got an `.exe` that runs perfectly fine as long as the `dll` is keeping it company in the same folder.

On to a harder problem: [The library I ultimately want to have compiled](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial)
after playing around with the `#include`s and moving some files around to make sure everyone can find their header, I compiled each source file (for windows - to my understanding, `_WIN32` is automatically defined when preprocessing) the same way I did `add.c` (sans `ADD_EXPORTS`), plus a file of my own, called `Source.cpp` (I did not create a header for it)

```
#include "serial/serial.h"
#include <combaseapi.h>

using serial::Serial;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using serial::PortInfo;
Serial* sp = NULL;

extern "C" {

    __declspec(dllexport) bool __cdecl createConnection(const char* port, uint32_t baudrate)
    {
        try {
            sp = new Serial(port, baudrate);
            return true;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

After making a `.obj` file of them all, I attempted to invoke the linker, with all of the `.obj` files I've generated, using `link /DLL /NOENTRY Source.obj list_ports/list_ports_win.obj win.obj serial.obj`

for which I got [134 errors](https://pastebin.com/9q7XK4vc)

Information on how to create a DLL without visual studio seems to be quite scarce, and I can't find anything useful about the errors I've looked up (no common mistake I could find when looking up the error + symbol)

What's the problem here?

Edit: Thanks to a comment I managed to find out I have a problem linking to CRT libraries. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005324/linking-to-crt-unresolved-external-symbol-winmaincrtstartup) helped me cut down on the number of errors, I will see if I can figure anything out about the new output I get and edit further

new linking commands:
`link /DLL /NOENTRY Source.obj list_ports/list_ports_win.obj win.obj serial.obj /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Redist/MSVC/14.29.30036/x64/Microsoft.VC142.CRT"`

Edit 2:
compiling the source files with `cl /c /clr source_file` led to [significantly fewer errors](https://pastebin.com/tgeYcEG0) when linking without specifying the `LIBPATH`. I think I might even be able to resolve all those by myself. I will continue to work on this later.

Comment: If you are going to use the dll in a native c++ or c in msvc you will want to change `__declspec(dllexport)` to a macro that switches between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on if you are building the dll or using it. Also you will need to link to the import library in your application. This Microsoft tutorial covers the details: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: The other errors seem to be related to the CRT.

Comment: The library you want compiled appears to already support msvc in multiple ways. I would try using CMake but it appears there is also a visual studio project.

Comment: @drescherjm I am not planning to use it in a native C/C++, Unity (game engine, uses C#) offers a way to create an "internal DLL" given a proper source file, so the `import`ing is done in C#. Unfortunately, just providing the code as-is doesn't work, so I'm trying to learn how the whole thing works so I can figure out how to use what little control I have over the compilation process.

Comment: Why do you need to build it? Especially via cmdline (why not using the *.vcxproj* files)?

Comment: @CristiFati I assumed I do based on a comment on another question I've since deleted (because the comment made me think the issue was elsewhere). My problem has been solved (by changing `.cc` file extensions to `.cpp`). but I am still curious and would like a better understanding of how the process works, though considering how little attention the question is getting, looks like I won't get it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *Serial* last official version (*v1.2.1*) was released in April 2015 (*20150422*), and the activity has dropped significantly since then.

Please check [[SO]: Linking to CRT (unresolved external symbol WinMainCRTStartup) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005324/linking-to-crt-unresolved-external-symbol-winmaincrtstartup/71872682#71872682) (just posted) before going further.

I just built the package and placed the artefacts at [[GitHub]: (master) CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - Prebuilt-Binaries/Serial/v024f80634f40073a41be43e956b5ebaca17f6167](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/Serial/v024f80634f40073a41be43e956b5ebaca17f6167) (the original code only builds a static library, I enhanced it to also build a dynamic one). Follow the download and "install" instructions.

The attempted scenario is building a *.dll* from your source code, that uses the downloaded *Serial* library.

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071859149]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 >nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> Source.cpp
>
> [prompt]> set LIBSERIAL_DIR=c:\Program Files\WjwWood\Serial\024f80634f40073a41be43e956b5ebaca17f6167
>
> [prompt]> :: Build with static libserial
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /I"%LIBSERIAL_DIR%\include" /EHsc /MD /c Source.cpp /FoSource_stat.obj
> Source.cpp
>
> [prompt]> link /NOLOGO /DLL /LIBPATH:"%LIBSERIAL_DIR%\lib" Source_stat.obj libserialstatic.lib
>    Creating library Source_stat.lib and object Source_stat.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> Source.cpp
> Source_stat.dll
> Source_stat.exp
> Source_stat.lib
> Source_stat.obj
>
> [prompt]> :: Build with dynamic libserial
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /I"%LIBSERIAL_DIR%\include" /EHsc /MD /DLIBSERIAL_DYNAMIC /c Source.cpp /FoSource_dyn.obj
> Source.cpp
>
> [prompt]> link /NOLOGO /DLL /LIBPATH:"%LIBSERIAL_DIR%\lib" Source_dyn.obj libserial.lib
>    Creating library Source_dyn.lib and object Source_dyn.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir
>  Volume in drive E is SSD0-WORK
>  Volume Serial Number is AE9E-72AC
>
>  Directory of e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071859149
>
> 22/04/15  01:58    <DIR>          .
> 22/04/15  01:58    <DIR>          ..
> 22/04/15  01:50               394 Source.cpp
> 22/04/15  01:58            17,920 Source_dyn.dll
> 22/04/15  01:58               704 Source_dyn.exp
> 22/04/15  01:58             1,778 Source_dyn.lib
> 22/04/15  01:57            47,856 Source_dyn.obj
> 22/04/15  01:55            41,472 Source_stat.dll
> 22/04/15  01:55               707 Source_stat.exp
> 22/04/15  01:55             1,790 Source_stat.lib
> 22/04/15  01:55            46,299 Source_stat.obj
>                9 File(s)        158,920 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  24,132,493,312 bytes free
> ```

A "graphical" comparison between the 2 generated *.dll*s. Notice that the variant linked with *libserial.lib* requires *libserial.dll*:

[image: Img0]

Comment: Incredible! thank you very much. I've gone over it and will do so again later to check out all the flags I don't recognize.

Comment: You're welcome! :) In the *URL*s that I pointed out (I know it's a lot, but I think it's useful) there's a reference to the official documentation about all the flags.